# How to create a AFHttpClient with different parameterEncoding for different Request Methods?

Tags: afnetworking

I'm new to AFNetworking but so far liking the abstraction.

I'm creating a subclass of AFHttpClient and I'd like to set the parameter encoding to JSON but ONLY for POST requests, is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by overriding `requestWithMethod:path:parameters:`, and setting the parameter encoding according to the specified `method`. Since all requests created by the client go through this method, it will work as expected.